# Congruence Equation Problem Question Solve for x

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I am trying to solve:

$x = 1(\mod13), x = 2(\mod31)$. Using the chinese remainder theorem, I got $x = 31*8 + 13 *y$, where I don't know what $y$ is, since I don't know how to solve $x = 13(\mod31)$. Please help!

Comment: See the first dupe link for how the CRT formula works, and the other links for various ways to compute the modular inverses in the formula.

Answer (score 0):

According to the schema for the explicit construction of $x$, $y$ should be $2\cdot13^{-1}\bmod31$. We can find the inverse of $13$ using the extended Euclidean algorithm, and it works out to be $12$, so $y=24$.